# mapping form value in angular 2 to get specific object

Tags: json, forms, angular, object, angular2-formbuilder

I'm currently returning an object when i submit my form and making it into a string because my service is expecting a string value.

However...when i call the function it returns my form object and puts it in a 'value' object and im not really sure how to call just the object inside the 'value'e object. Can anyone help?

my onsubmit function:

```
submitEvent(value: any): void {
   // this.loading = true;

   let stringEvent: string = JSON.stringify({value});

   this.eventService.create(stringEvent).subscribe(result => {
     if (result === true) {
       this.loading = false;
     } else {
       this.error = 'Username or password is incorrect';
       this.loading = false;
     }
   });
 }
```

my form:

```
<form [formGroup]="eventForm" class="form-horizontal style-form" name="form" (ngSubmit)="submitEvent(eventForm.value)" novalidate>
```

what it returns:

```
{
  "value": {
    "name": "",
    "description": "",
    "attendeeCountMax": "",
    "attendeeCountMin": "",
    "costMax": "",
    "responseDeadline": "",
    "eventDates": {
      "startDate": "",
      "endDate": "",
      "type": 1
    },
    "location": {
      "cost": 0,
      "costDescription": "string",
      "costType": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "uri": "string"
    },
    "startDate": "2016-11-11T16:11:11.773Z"
  }
}
```

I just want whats inside the "value" object

Comment: Why not just use: `let stringEvent: string = JSON.stringify({value.value});`? `ngSubmit()` returns the `$event: Event`- Not the form values. [Read the docs!](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgForm-directive.html#!#onSubmit-anchor)

Comment: If that is no suitable comment provide some of your html form so we can see how you have set up the controls/groups to provide the given structure.

Comment: You don't need to pass 'eventForm' to submit method since it's already a class member. And then you also can use the 'getRawValue()' function to return an object that can then be serialized using 'JSON.stringify()'.